# WebODM cant find docker

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on an Ubuntu 16.04 Server and it seems to be working. I'm trying to run WebODM which requires docker but cant seem to find it. I get the following error.

handyman@ubuntu:/WebODM$ ./webodm.sh start
Checking for docker...   OK
Checking for git...   OK
Checking for python...   OK
Checking for pip...   OK
Checking for docker-compose...   OK
Starting WebODM...

## Using the following environment:

Host: localhost
Port: 8000
Media directory: appmedia
SSL: NO
SSL key: 
SSL certificate: 
SSL insecure port redirect: 80

## Celery Broker: redis://broker

Make sure to issue a ./webodm.sh down if you decide to change the environment.

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.nodeodm.yml -f docker-compose.plugins.yml start || docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.nodeodm.yml -f docker-compose.plugins.yml up
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Here is the output from ip route

handyman@ubuntu:/WebODM$ ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eno1 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.50 
10.0.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.50 linkdown 
169.254.0.0/16 dev eno1  scope link  metric 1000 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown

Thanks

Comment: did you add handyman user to docker group.  usermod -aG docker handyman

Comment: That did the trick... thanks so much... did not expect to resolve this so quickly and easily... you are the man ;) thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by Khimananda Oli, you can add handyman user to the `docker` group. However, please mark, that **this introduces [a vulnerability](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface) on your host.** I recommend running the script with `sudo`.